# Datetime picker does not appear in Telerik Kendo SpreadSheet

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, spreadsheet, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to display date-time picker for specific columns but the date-time picker does not appear like this example but I need a time 
Here's [a link](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/spreadsheet/validation)!

Or at least show date-time-picker for a cell.

Comment: How can we help you if you don't show your code ?

Comment: i take the same code in the link but i want to display a date picker and time picker for the same cell